# Inconsistent stderr output between shell and systemd

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, systemd

I have a little script running at startup:

At first i was using crontab with *@reboot* tag, but, since some time i need to modify the script, i ended up looking at systemd for an easy restart of the script

---

my crontab config was:

```
@reboot sleep 10; cd /path/to/the/script/ && nohup ./script.py >> stdout.txt 2>> stderr.txt
```

and everything was working fine

---

I'm now using systemd with this config:

```
[Unit]
Description=Script

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/the/script/
ExecStart=/path/to/the/script/script.py
StandardOutput=file:/path/to/the/script/stdout.txt
StandardError=file:/path/to/the/script/stderr.txt     <----- Problem here
User=my_user

[Install]
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

---

the problem is:

- **before stderr was correctoly written to stderr.txt**
- **now both stdout and stderr are written to stdout.txt, even if i specified a different file for stderr**

---

There are also no errors looking at

```
journalctl -e -u python-coolosseo
```

---

BTW i tried both file: and append:

Comment: A known and hopefully fixed bug: https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10875

Comment: So i just need to wait while the update is being published to the Ubuntu's repo?

Comment: I don't use Ubuntu, but I expect you'll have to wait for Ubuntu 19.04 to have the fixed systemd available in the repo.